Matter.js - Handling collisions at high object speeds in matter.js
I'm currently working on a space flight simulator using matter.js as a game engine. I'm facing a problem with the huge size of the map. If we consider that 1 metre is 10px (adjusted to the size of spacecraft), the map of the solar system is huge, which matter cannot handle. So matter.js can't handle such high speeds as 7.6 km/h (76,000 px/s), it can't correctly process object collisions. Also, is it necessary to render the exact size of the planets? So I'm wondering if you have any ideas on how to work around these limitations.
I will be glad to hear your advice

MJS is just a simulator, not physically accurate, as is the case with most game physics engines. Can you share a [mcve] of your problem?

"is it necessary to render the exact size of the planets?" is up to you to decide! But I'd think probably not, since you'd need a monitor the size of a solar system to make the experience playable.

You can try to add a collision sphere with a better accuracy to all the objects which are moving.

At first detection approach you can look for a possible collision
Look through all candidates for a possible collision. Each gets a collision sphere with a higher accuracy, Use this adapted accuracy to look for a more detailed collision detection.

